# Why is text darker than a filled shape of the same RGB colour in powerpoint?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

When filling text and a solid shape fill or slide background with the same RGB colour values, the text appears darker than the shape or background. This makes the colour inconsistent when using the same swatch from a colour theme for text and fills.
Frustrating for clients who want the simplicity of a consistent colour template.